# Why LSTM Output_shape different from input_shape

Tags: tensorflow, keras, lstm

I have a multi layer LSTM Model; My problem is the first layer has a different output_shape (Different number of features) from the input shape. Because of this, I cannot fit the model; an error is throwing. Can you explain why this happens and any solution will be much appreciated.

```
trainingModel = keras.Sequential()

print('training_batch_size : ',training_batch_size, 'DataX.shape[1] : ',trainingDataX.shape[1],'DataX.shape[2] : ', trainingDataX.shape[2])

trainingModel.add(keras.layers.LSTM(numberOfNeurons
                    , batch_input_shape=(training_batch_size, trainingDataX.shape[1], trainingDataX.shape[2])
                    , return_sequences=True
                    , stateful=True
                    , dropout = keyDropOut))

for idx in range(numberOfLSTMLayers - 1):

    trainingModel.add(keras.layers.LSTM(
        numberOfNeurons
        , return_sequences= True
        , dropout = keyDropOut * (idx +1)
        ))

trainingModel.compile(optimizer='adam',loss='mean_squared_error')#,metrics=['accuracy'])

#Model Layer Shapes ========================
for layer in trainingModel.layers:

    print('Input shape', layer.input_shape)
    print('Output shape', layer.output_shape)



Output
===============
training_batch_size :  96 trainingDataX.shape[1] :  10 trainingDataX.shape[2] :  4
Model Layer Shapes
Input shape (96, 10, 4)
Output shape (96, 10, 5) *<<<THIS IS MY PROBLEM
Input shape (96, 10, 5)
Output shape (96, 10, 5)
Input shape (96, 10, 5)
Output shape (96, 10, 5)


Finally when I fit the model, it trhows error like:

ValueError: A target array with shape (2880, 10, 4) was passed for an output of shape (96, 10, 5) while using as loss `mean_squared_error`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output
```

Comment: Never mind; Solved it, the First Layer of LSTM should have number of neurons = number of features; i.e in first layer there should be only 4 neurons where I used 5.

Comment: The first dimension of the target array is 2880 and that of the output array is 96. The number of samples in the input array does not match the number of labels.

Comment: @ShubhamPanchal, Thanks for looking into it. First dimension of output array 96 simply means the batch size, so thats not a problem. Anyway got it working with number of neuron in first LSTM layer = number features.

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question as I solved it: The First Layer of LSTM should have number of neurons = number of features; i.e in first layer there should be only 4 neurons where I used 5.